# How to manage audio in and out from and to file of Huawei GSM modems?

Tags: python, bash, audio, serial-port, at-command

I've got a Huawei E173 USB dongle connected to a Raspberry PI.
I'm trying to use the device to make and receive calls.

For my purpose, it is needed (i) to save audio of the call to file and (ii) to send audio to the telephony call from an input file.

As far as I understood (I can't find any official guide), the E173 dongle sets up three new devices (please correct me if I'm wrong):

- `/dev/ttyUSB0` for commands
- `/dev/ttyUSB1` for voice data
- `/dev/ttyUSB2` for notifications

In order to enable phone calls, I run the following commands: `AT+CLIP=1`, `AT+CRC=1`, `AT+CNMI=1,2` on `/dev/ttyUSB0`.
Also, if I run `AT^CVOICE?` I get `^CVOICE:0,8000,16,20`.
Finally, when I make/receive calls, I run `AT^DDSETEX=2` on `/dev/ttyUSB0` to enable audio forward to the `/dev/ttyUSB1` port.

At this point, I'm stuck.

I know there are [other similar posts trying to redirect microphone input and speakers output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439119/how-to-get-audio-in-and-out-of-huawei-gsm-modems-when-doing-a-voice-call) to the dongle, but my aim is to save the conversation to file (during a call, I tried to run `cat /dev/ttyUSB1 > filename.raw`, but the file can't be opened with standard software, hence, how can I convert it?) and, simultaneously, to send voice from file (which format? I tried to send back the `filename.raw` to `/dev/ttyUSB1` with `cat filename.raw > /dev/ttyUSB1`, but the entire system gets freezed).

How can I save audio to file and send back audio from file?

I found [some resources](https://weekly-geekly.github.io/articles/192930/index.html) on the Internet trying to explain, for similar devices, that audio has to be sent in mono, in digital frequency of 8000 Hz, and digitalized to 16 bit. By looking at the result of the `AT^CVOICE?` command, such parameters should be applied also in my case.
Also, the same resource tells that "audio data should be fed to the modem audio port in batches of 320 bytes every 0.02 seconds".
I've tried to apply even such approach, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stuck trying to get audio from a huawei E153.. if I use the 'Huawei Mobile Partner' software. I can use the pc sound to hear and talk during a voice call, so I know it is possible for sure. I read that someone could manage to get the sound form a Huawei Mobile modem in ubuntu, take a look here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/464661/way-to-call-through-huawei-modem-in-14-04-e303

Comment: Nothing native without any need of third party software? Just to let you know, my aim is to create some kind of automated voicemail to integrate in https://github.com/auino/virtualphone

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31553460)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org/) with [chan_dongle](https://github.com/haha8x/asterisk-chan-dongle-16) to manage calls/messages on  Huawei GSM Modems. From there on you should be able to do whatever you want via Asterisk instead of using virtualphone. There seems to be an [asterisk telegram gateway](https://github.com/Infactum/tg2sip) and [asterisk native voicemail support](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Configuring+Voice+Mail+Boxes) as also [call recording is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062729/asterisk-and-recording-incoming-and-outgoing-calls).

`AT^CVOICE?` should show the status if voice function is enabled on the modem.

`^CVOICE:(1)` means that voice is disabled.

`^CVOICE:(0)` means that voice is enabled.

If the modem has voice support, what is depending on the model and firmware/dashboard version, you should be able to enable voice support:

`AT^CVOICE=0`

If after enabling voice, `AT^CVOICE?` still shows `^CVOICE:(1)` then the modem/firmware probably lacks voice support. I don't have much experience with different modem models, I use model E1550 and E180 where this works fine.